# Updatind serialized output when adding element to list (hack of Bushell's jQuery Nestable)

Tags: jquery, dynamically-generated, jquery-callback

I hacked David Bushell's Nestable jQuery plugin ([here](http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/)) in order to build an interface for adding/removing and sorting users associated with assignments.
We usually start with a predefined list which you can order and the output is serialized upon each change. You should also add new elements or remove existing elements from the list and the serialized output **should**, obviously, update again.

**The Pen with the HTML, CSS, JS is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rabBpP).**

As you can see I am adding/substacting elements on checkbox check/uncheck but I assume I would have to also trigger the `updateOutput` function as well. I got stuck here :( How do I get the JS code to update the serialized output when adding and substracting elements from the list?

**UPDATE:**

This is how it seems to work:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
  .....
}).on('change', function() {
    updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output'))); 
});
```

However, if I mimic the behavior used when initializing nestable up in the script it does not work. Why?

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
  .....
}).on('change', updateOutput);
```